# Connect Laravel Framework 5.6.27 and PHP 7.1.9 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, pdo, sql-server-2014

I'm coding an app using Laravel 5.6.27, PHP 7.1.9 and SQL Server 2014 and I tried several solutions found online (most are lower in the version I am using) including from this site.

Basically here's what I have done so far,

Configured .env  to this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydatabasename
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

database.php to this:

line 16:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
```

line 70:

```
    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

I also tried replacing those entries in line 70 with the actual credentials,still unsuccessful.

I also tried this extension both from SQLSRV52.EXE and SQLSRV43.EXE and from unofficial releases.

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll
```

Here's the error i encountered when i run `php artisan migrate`:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations)
```

and when i run `DB::connection()->getPdo();`

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.6 (PHP 7.1.9 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> DB::connection()->getPdo();
PDOException with message 'could not find driver'
>>>
```

Additionally, I'm not sure if with this error in login page `"SQLSTATE[HY000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Protocol error in TDS stream (SQL: select top 1 * from [users] where [email] = test1234@gmail.com)"` means it was able to find the driver thru web login and just php artisan that can find the driver.

I hope someone can enlighten me on this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try the extensions separately or all at once?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Had no problem installing the drivers I just can't do anything except create the connection after its made every request gets a TDS Stream error.

Answer (score 0):

In `.env` file, you have the port `3306` (mysql). Should be `1433` for Sql.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Stefan said, also use a view where you just put phpinfo().

This is just to check if you have installed pdo extension for sql server.

It should look like that:

[image]

If not, you should install that extension.

And also pay attention on the others parameters in .env file like DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, etc because they take precedence over the values set in database.php